# scanf multiple variables or one variable

Tags: c

In C, I need to input four variables using scanf

`scanf("%c %d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4)`

the first variable may take two values 'c' and 'q'

when I enter c then I enter the other variables it will do some calculations but when I want to quit I should enter 'q' only and not enter the rest of the variables but scanf does not move forward until I enter the rest of the variables

is there anyway to solve it, I am not sure if it is possible using scanf but if there is another function then I don't mind using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "is there anyway to solve it"

Read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` ...

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
```

.. and then scan it

```
  char v1;
  int v2,v2,v3;
  int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%c %d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &v3, &v4);
  if (cnt >= 1 && v1 == 'q') Quit();
  else if (cnt == 4 && v1 == 'c') Do_stuff(v2,v3,v4);
  else puts("Bad input");
```

Comment: Looks great I will try it and get back to you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use multiple scanfs for this. For example

```
scanf("%c", &v1);
if(v1 == 'c'){
    scanf("%d %d %d",&v2, &v3, &v4);
    /*some staff*/
}
else{
    /*another staff*/ 
}
```

Comment: This works but it is not exactly what I want because I will have to press enter after inserting the c or q letter and this is not the desired behaviour

Comment: @TamimMohammedAli no you don't!

Comment: (Also remember to check the return value of `scanf`s)